# Mover solo el archivo más nuevo de una carpeta a otra carpeta

Tags: script, batch

Tengo esto hecho y no me funciona hora

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir C:\Users\fdiaz\Desktop\1\* /b /a-d /od') do set ultimo=%%a
xcopy "C:\Users\fdiaz\Desktop\%ultimo%" "C:\Users\fdiaz\Desktop\2"
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.solvetic.com/tutoriales/article/4958-copiar-mover-archivos-carpetas-con-comandos-windows-10-8-7/

Solucin añadir estos parametros a tu scrip.

**/D m-d-a**

Copia los archivos modificados en la fecha específica o después, en caso de no indicar ninguna fecha, copia sólo los archivos cuya hora de origen es más reciente que la hora de destino.

**1. Comando XCOPY para copiar archivos desde CMD Windows 10**

XCOPY (Copiar) es un comando desarrollado para copiar uno o varios archivos a otra ubicación especifica dentro de Windows.

**Paso 2**

```
La sintaxis general que usar con COPY es la siguiente con XCOPY parámetros:
XCOPY origen [destino] [/A | /M] [/D[:fecha]] [/P] [/S [/E]] [/V] [/W]
                           [/C] [/I] [/Q] [/F] [/L] [/H] [/R] [/T] [/U]
                           [/K] [/N] [/O] [/X] [/Y] [/-Y] [/Z]
                           [/EXCLUDE:archivo1[+archivo2][+archivo3]...]
```

**Paso 3**

Ahora, los parámetros aquí expuestos son los siguientes:

**Origen**
Indica los archivos que vamos a copiar.

**Destino**
Especifica la ubicación y/o el nombre de los nuevos archivos.

**/A**

Copia sólo los archivos con el atributo de archivo establecido, no cambia el atributo actual.

**/M**

Copia sólo los archivos con el atributo del archivo establecido, desactivando el atributo del archivo.

**/D m-d-a**

Copia los archivos modificados en la fecha específica o después, en caso de no indicar ninguna fecha, copia sólo los archivos cuya hora de origen es más reciente que la hora de destino.

**/EXCLUDE archivo1 +archivo2 +archivo3**

Indica una lista de archivos que contiene cadenas. Cuando alguna de las cadenas coincida con alguna parte de la ruta de acceso absoluta del archivo que se va a copiar, ese archivo se excluirá de la copia.

**/EXCLUDE archivo1[+archivo2][+archivo3]**

**/P**

Solicita confirmación antes de crear cada archivo de destino.

**/S**

Copia los directorios y subdirectorios excepto los vacíos.

**/E**

Copia los directorios y subdirectorios, incluidos los vacíos.

**/V**

Comprueba la integridad de cada archivo nuevo.

**/W**

Solicita que presione una tecla antes de copiar.

**/C**

Sigue copiando incluso si se producen errores.

**/L**

Si el destino no existe y se copia más de un archivo, se supone que el destino debe ser un directorio.

**/Q**

No muestra los nombres de archivo mientras se copian.

**/F**

Despliega los nombres de archivo de origen y de destino completos mientras se copian.

**/L**

Muestra los archivos que se serán copiados.

**/H**

Copia también los archivos ocultos y de sistema.

**/R**

Sobrescribe los archivos de sólo lectura.

**/T**

Crea la estructura de directorios, pero no copia los archivos. No incluye los directorios vacíos ni los subdirectorios.

**/T/E**

incluye los directorios vacíos y los subdirectorios.

**/U**

Sólo copia los archivos que ya existen en el destino.

**/K**

Copia los atributos. Xcopy normal restablecerá los atributos de sólo lectura.

**/N**

Copia haciendo uso de los nombres cortos generados.

**/O**

Copia la información de la ACL y de miembros de los archivos.

**/X**

Copia la configuración de auditoría (implica /O).

**/Y**

Suprime el mensaje para confirmar que desea sobrescribir un archivo de destino existente.

**/-Y**

Despliega un mensaje para confirmar si desea sobrescribir un archivo de destino existente.

**/Z**

Copia los archivos de red en modo reiniciable.